# How to reduce number of hierarchical 'if statements'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

```
<% @descriptions.each_with_index do |description, i| %>
  <% description.tale2.each do |tax_ref| %>            
    <% if condition %>              
      <% if condition %>
        <% if condition %>                  
          <%= $text_first_describe%> <%= $paren_author_yr %>
             <% ref_sp_uniq.each_with_index do |ref, i| %>
               <% if ref == tax_ref.ref_wo_brace%>
                  <% execution %>                      
               <% elsif i == (ref_sp_uniq.size - 1)%>
                  <%# @ref_desc = "#{@ref_desc_numb}. #{tax_ref.ref_wo_brace}" %>
               <% end %>
             <% end %>
          <% if condition %>
                  <% execution %>                      
          <% elsif condition %>
            <% execution %>
          <% elsif taxon_name.emend_author_year %>                    
             <%= print %>
          <% else %>                    
             <%= print %>                    
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <% if condition %>
          <%= print %>
          <% ref_sp_uniq.each_with_index do |ref, i| %>
             <% if condition %>
                <% execution %>                      
             <% elsif condition %>
                  <% execution %>                      
             <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <% if condition %>
            <% execution %>                      
          <% elsif condition %>
            <% execution %>                      
          <% elsif condition %>
            <% execution %>                      
          <% else %>
            <% execution %>                      
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>        
<% end %>
```

Comment: try to edit your code with a good completion

Comment: that depend your condition. Its almost impossible to help your without more information

Comment: As it stands this question is _impossible_ to answer. Without knowing what conditions are being checked or what code is being executed there is literally _nothing_ we can suggest. Maybe you are repeating code, or maybe several chunks of code could just be run under a single check, but we simply do not know. We need the actual code with conditions _and_ execution before we can do anything.

Comment: -1: please edit your question, use code formatting (four spaces at the start of each line) and provide some context.

Comment: Ruby has 'case when' statement that is pretty nifty and when used properly can help a lot with complicated if statements because 'case when' allows range checking which comes up a lot in conditional code.

Comment: This looks like code to post if you're trolling. It's practically line noise and ruby is one of the most expressive languages I know but this manages to make it look bad.

Comment: See [Flattening arrow code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you can try inverting the condition on your outermost if block, and work your way in.  This will often result in less nesting, eg:

```
if condition1
  if condition2
    #ifblock
  else
    #elseblock2
  end
else
  #elseblock
end
```

Inside a loop, as you have your code, it would become this strcture, which is less nested:

```
if !condition
  #elseblock
  next
end
if !condition2
  #elseblock2
  next
end
#ifblock
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use the operators `||` and `&&` ?

im not at all literate with the syntax but you should be able to convert:

```
<% if condition %>            
  <% if condition %>
     <% if condition %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

into:

```
<% if condition && condition && condition %>
    <% expression %>
<% end %>
```

Looking at the docs this logical expressions are available!

also removing the language identifiers you should be able to do:

```
<%
    if condition && condition && condition
        expression
    end
%>
```

When it comes down to the `else if`'s then you can increase readability by doing a switch statement:

The main point is to remove the not so required `<%` and `%>` in places.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#and

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you should do with this template, and templates that look like this in general:

1. Break some elements into partials.
2. Push logic to the model. Instead of

   ```
    <% if condition with model %>
      stuff
    <% else %>
      other stuff
    <% end %>
   ```

   when stuff or other stuff are strings with little or no markup, do

   ```
    <%= model.display_for_condition %>
   ```
3. Use helpers for cases like 2) where the things to be displayed have some markup:

   ```
    <% condition_helper(model.condition?) %>
   ```
4. Use presenter objects, especially when dealing with display logic that references more than one model.
5. Most abstractly, but most importantly for learning to write code with fewer if statements, internalize one of the key distinctions between OO style and procedural style code: with OO you ask objects to do things they know how to do. If you find yourself always asking objects for information and deciding what to do with it, you are using objects as nothing more than structs and writing procedural code.

   Or as my intern described it the other day: (this has become one of my favourite quotes about programming)

> if you're itchy it's ok to scratch your own itch, but it would be kind of weird to scratch other people's itches.

Answer (score 1):

A thing to try: case statement

```
case tax_ref
when a then execution1
when b then execution2
end
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm